# Cambiar valor de un elemento en array

Tags: php

En una clase genero un array, pero antes del *break* quiero modificar el último elemento poniendo `importe_s = $saldo - $deuda`.
Para el ejemplo solamente son dos registros pero pueden ser mucho más.

```
$sql = "SELECT  CONDICION";
        $bd = new ConexionDB();
        $stmt = $bd->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindParam('codigo', $codigo, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->execute();
if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0) { 
    $saldo = 0;
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $CtacteSaldoVO = new CtacteSaldoVO();
        $CtacteSaldoVO->set_id($row['id']);
        $CtacteSaldoVO->set_importe_s($row['importe_s']);
        $CtacteSaldoVO->set_saldo($saldo = $saldo + $row['importe_s']);
        $registros[] = $CtacteSaldoVO;
        $fila = $row['id'];
        $importe = $row['importe_s'];
        if ($deuda <= $saldo) {
            $diferencia = $saldo - $deuda;
            $registros['$fila']['importe_s'] = $importe - $diferencia;
            break;
        }
    return $registros;
```

Este es el array generado.

```
Array ( 
[0] => CtacteSaldoVO Object (
[_saldo:CtacteSaldoVO:private] => 400 
[_id:CtacteVO:private] => 45986 
[_importe_s:CtacteVO:private] => 400.00 

[1] => CtacteSaldoVO Object (
[_saldo:CtacteSaldoVO:private] => 800 
[_id:CtacteVO:private] => 45704 
[_importe_s:CtacteVO:private] => 400.00 

) 
[$fila] => Array ( [importe_s] => 340 ) )
```

Y quiero modificar el último `id=45704` (en este caso).
Esos 340 que aparecen al final debería actualizar a 400 del `id=45704`.
Será porque hay un objeto dentro del array?

Comment: ponle comillas simples o dobles al **id** en esta variable: `$row[id];`  sino se cree que es una constante y no una clave. Es decir: `$row['id'];`

Comment: Actualicé la pregunta. Igual no hace lo que tiene que hacer.

Comment: ¿Qué hace esta línea? `($registros['$fila'] => $diferencia);`

Comment: Actualicé la pregunta, ahora se entiende mejor.

Comment: No entiendo tu pregunta. ¿Quieres modificar el último registro que haya dentro del `while`? Por otra parte, el Manual de PHP es claro en cuanto al uso de `rowCount()`, no debes confiar en él para contar filas en consultas del tipo `SELECT`, tu código puede ser erróneo en algunos contextos. Sea como sea, pulsa en [edit] y aclara tu problema. Una solución óptima sería obtener tus datos en un array y luego verificar el último dato contra el total de filas, o aplicar la lógica deseada en la misma instrucción SQL. Parecería que le tiras a PHP un problema que debió resolver la BD.

Comment: Exacto, quiero modificar el valor del último registro  del array generado pero me aparece esa línea `[$fila] => Array ( [importe_s] => 340 ) )`. Y con respecto a hacerlo todo en bd, bueno, no se me ocurre cómo podría hacerlo. Tal vez cambiar la lógica completamente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si quieres aplicar un cálculo particular al último registro de un conjunto de resultados la forma más simple es guardar en un array todos tus resultados y luego en la lectura de esos datos determinar cuál es el último registro.

De paso, podrás evitar la mala práctica que consiste en usar `rowCount()` para determinar el total de filas que trae tu consulta. El [Manual de PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.rowcount.php) es claro cuando dice que `rowCount()` no debería usarse para consultas del tipo `SELECT`:

> Si la última sentencia SQL ejecutada por el objeto PDOStatement
> asociado fue una sentencia `SELECT`, algunas bases de datos podrían
> devolver el número de filas devuelto por dicha sentencia. Sin embargo,
> este comportamiento no está garantizado para todas las bases de datos
> y no debería confiarse en él para aplicaciones portables.

Aplicando lo dicho, el código quedaría así:

```
$finalData=array(); # Variable que será retornada al final
$sql = "SELECT  CONDICION";
$bd = new ConexionDB();
$stmt = $bd->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam('codigo', $codigo, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();
$allRows=array();
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $allRows[] = $row;
}

if ($allRows) {
    /*
        Determinamos el último elemento del array
        Si usas PHP 7.3 o superior basta con esto:
        $lastKey = array_key_last($allRows);
        Si usas PHP inferior a 7.3, 
        ver "Verificar el último indice en PHP anterior a 7.3"
    */
    $lastKey = array_key_last($allRows);

    foreach ($allRows as $k => $row) {
        $saldo = 0;
        $CtacteSaldoVO = new CtacteSaldoVO();
        $CtacteSaldoVO->set_id($row['id']);
        $CtacteSaldoVO->set_importe_s($row['importe_s']);
        $CtacteSaldoVO->set_saldo($saldo = $saldo + $row['importe_s']);
        $registros[] = $CtacteSaldoVO;
        $fila = $row['id'];
        $importe = $row['importe_s'];
        if ($k == $lastKey) {
            # Este es el último elemento, haz el cálculo que corresponda
        } 
        $finalData[] = $CtacteSaldoVO;
    }
}

return $finalData;
```

#### Verificar el último indice en PHP anterior a 7.3

Dado que `array_key_last()` no existe en las versiones de PHP anteriores a 7.3, si es tu caso, debes escribir el código así:

```
if ($allRows) {
    /*
        Determinamos el último elemento del array
        Esto sólo se haría en versiones de PHP inferiores a 7.3
    */
    $numItems = count($allRows);
    $i = 0;

    foreach ($allRows as $k => $row) {
        $saldo = 0;
        $CtacteSaldoVO = new CtacteSaldoVO();
        $CtacteSaldoVO->set_id($row['id']);
        $CtacteSaldoVO->set_importe_s($row['importe_s']);
        $CtacteSaldoVO->set_saldo($saldo = $saldo + $row['importe_s']);
        $registros[] = $CtacteSaldoVO;
        $fila = $row['id'];
        $importe = $row['importe_s'];
        if(++$i === $numItems) {
            # Este es el último elemento, haz el cálculo que corresponda
        } 
        $finalData[] = $CtacteSaldoVO;
    }
}

return $finalData;
```